# How do I convert ISO-8859-8-i to UTF-8?

Tags: c, unicode, iconv

I received an email which uses the charset `iso-8859-8-i`. iconv says that it is an unsupported charset. I tried using `iso-8859-8` but that gives an error with "Invalid multibyte sequence." Any idea how to convert this string to UTF-8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just replace the encoding name with `"iso-8859-8"`. The `-i` suffix is to indicate that it's in logical order, not the backwards "visual order" that `"iso-8859-8"` traditionally meant. There's no way `iconv` can process "visual order" specially anyway, so it should convert it just fine.

As for "invalid multibyte sequence", perhaps you got the source/dest charset argument order backwards? If that's not the problem, then your file probably contains bytes which are not defined in the ISO-8859-8 charset, i.e. it's invalid...

Comment: thanks, yes, you were correct. i had a separate issue with decoding base64 encoded emails.

Comment: I have never seen a suffix used on a charset like that before. Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: I found it on Wikipedia... they claim it's an IANA charset code, but I don't see any reference. Anybody up for posting the "Citation Needed" template? ;-)

Comment: See [RFC1556](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1556) « Handling of Bi-directional Texts in MIME ».